# JNDI Lookup fails on Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere, jndi

I'm using Liberty Profile v8.5.5.5 (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150221-0034) on IBM J9 VM, version pxa6470sr1-20120330_01 (SR1) (en_US)

I have the jndi feature installed...but no matter what I do, I can't do a simple JNDI lookup.

In my server.xml

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName" value="plato" />
```

My code... (Which is just a servlet of a few lines)

```
Object jndiConstant = new InitialContext().lookup(
"schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName");
```

But this fails with:

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name schoolOfAthens not found in context "serverlocal:CELLROOT/SERVERROOT".

The code is taken directly from an example.

Any ideas?

I am running this locally and have also tried on my Bluemix account... Same result

Comment: Can you provide the list of features you had configured?

Answer (score 2):

ok , got this to work. I added a resource-ref to my web.xml and looked it up like this:

```
 Object obj2 = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName");`
```

web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
     <description>Test Reference</description>
     <res-ref-name>schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName</res-ref-name>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

Comment: Faced same issue and it helped.
But I had also few projects on WLP where this was working without changes in web.xml and adding "java:comp/env/".
And I'm not able to define what the key difference between those projects.

Answer (score 0):

Same works for me on 8.5.5.6, don't have .5 at hand but should work in the same way.

Here is my my server.xml:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>


    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <webApplication id="JNDITest" location="JNDITest.war" name="JNDITest"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName" value="plato" />    
</server>
```

And servlet code (take a look that you can also use `@Resource` annotation instead of lookup):

```
@WebServlet("/JNDIServlet")
public class JNDIServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(lookup="schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName")
    String jndiVariable;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            Object object = ctx.lookup("schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName");
            System.out.println("object: " + object);
            System.out.println("jndiVariable: " + jndiVariable);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

with output:

```
object: plato
jndiVariable: plato
```